# How do I create a many to many relationship with an existing record?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In my Django 1.11 blog app, I have a many to many relationship between `authors` and `posts`.

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='authors')
```

I could create a post with an author as follows:

```
$ post = Post.objects.create(title='My post')
$ post.authors.create(name='John Doe')
```

But how can I create a post and author explicitly and connect them through the association?

```
$ post = Post.objects.create(title='My post')
$ author = Author.create(name='John Doe')
$ post.authors.????(author)
```

If I call `post.authors.get_or_create(name='John Doe')` it would create a new author, which is not what I want.

I could access the join table directly by making it a separate model (`PostAuthor`), but is there a way to connect an existing author to the post through the QuerySet API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
post.authors.add(author)
```